# JS Promises POST request throws invalid json response body

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have written a POST client side JS method that when I run (the server side is up and running) I get the following error message:

```
 error { FetchError: invalid json response body at http://localhost:3000/addMovie reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
 at /home/workspace/node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:272:32
 at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:86:5)
 message:
'invalid json response body at http://localhost:3000/addMovie reason: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0',
 type: 'invalid-json' }
```

The contents of the client file are below. This is part of my attempt to learn JS Promises. It would be really helpful if you could please point me towards the right direction. To run this file, I just do `node getPost.js`

```
require('es6-promise').polyfill();
require('isomorphic-fetch');
// TODO
const postData = async ( url = '', data = {})=>{
    // console.log(data)
      const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
      credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data), // body data type must match "Content-Type" header        
    });

      try {
        const newData = await response.json();
        console.log(newData);
        return newData
      }catch(error) {
      console.log("error", error);
      // appropriately handle the error
      }
  }

  postData('http://localhost:3000/addMovie', '{"movie": "the matrix", "score": "5"}')
```

This is my `/addMovie` route definition.

```
const data = []
app.post('/addMovie', addMovie )
function addMovie (req, res){
    console.log(req.body)
    // data.push(req.body)
    res.send('POST received')

 }
```

Comment: Usually the `<` error happens when the server sends back some HTML when json is expected.  Your route isn't sending JSON, but it's not HTML either.  It should throw a different error "Unexpected token P" (for the P in "POST"), so it seems it's not being reached at all.  Can you show the result of `console.log(response)`?

Comment: So are you suggesting that the issue is on the server or on the client file?

Comment: Two problems on the server.  Your route isn't sending valid json, and it seems the route isn't being served for that url.  Change `response.json()` to `response.text()`-- since your route sends the string "POST received" instead of json-- and see what you get in the browser console.

Comment: Thank you. Then I get this though:       var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();  XMLHttpRequest is not defined

Comment: I suggest using a guide instead of trying to wing it, it seems there are several problems